# How to validate hook block configure form in Drupal 7

Tags: php, validation, drupal, drupal-hooks, drupal-blocks

In Drupal 7 [hook_block_configure](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_configure/7) and [hook_block_save](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_save/7) provide a method to modify a blocks settings and save these values.

But how would I carry out validation on the form before saving the values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As found [here](http://drupal.org/node/280585) when configuring your form element you should add an '#element_validate' that points to a custom validation function of the element. You can find more information in the Form Api [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#element_validate)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to add validation for the whole form, this is not really possible. The best way I have managed to implement myself is to add a custom function to the code with $edit as a parameter with Boolean as a return value. Then call the function in the `hook_block_save()` before saving data in order to perform the extra checks. Works fine with the only exception that it will not highlight in red values that are incorrect in the form.